# Как в Golang прервать выполнение кода?

Tags: golang, golang-faq

Как в Golang прервать выполнение кода? Аналог `exit()`/`die()` в PHP.

Есть

```
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    parametr=0    
    if  parametr!="1" {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Параметр=1")
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "текст после проверки")   //Я хочу это не отображать,если parametr!="1"
}
```

Нужно, если параметр не `1`, то выйти из функции (но не из приложения вообще).
Можно, конечно, поставить `else`, но везде тогда делать обёртки? Или можно как-то выйти из функции?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit

Comment: Я наверное не правильно выразился. Есть 
func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    parametr=0    
    if  parametr!="1" {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Параметр=1")
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "текст после проверки")   //Я хочу это не отображать,если parametr!="1"
}
//Нужно,если параметр не 1, то выйти из функции.(но не из приложения вообще)
Можно конечно поставить else , но везде тогда делать обёртки? или можно как-то выйти из функции

Comment: Вы хотите `return`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### выход

[func os.Exit(code int)](https://golang.org/pkg/os/#Exit)

> Exit causes the current program to exit with the given status code. Conventionally, code zero indicates success, non-zero an error. The program terminates immediately; deferred functions are not run.

мой вольный перевод:

> Exit вызывает завершение текущей программы с указанным кодом завершения. принято считать, что код `0` означает успешное завершение, а не-нулевой код означает ошибку. программа завершается немедленно, отложенные функции не вызываются.

### возврат

[return [ ExpressionList ]](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Return_statements)

> A "return" statement in a function F terminates the execution of F, and optionally provides one or more result values. Any functions deferred by F are executed before F returns to its caller.

мой вольный перевод:

> оператор "return" в функции "F" прерывает выполнение "F" и (опционально) возвращает один или более результатов. любые функции, «отложенные» функцией "F", выполняются перед тем, как управление вернётся в вызывавшую "F" функцию.

примеры:

```
func noResult() {
    return
}

func simpleF() int {
    return 2
}

func complexF1() (re float64, im float64) {
    return -7.0, -4.0
}
```

Comment: Я наверно не так выразился. Мне нужно выйти из текущей функции, а не из приложения

Comment: дополнил ответ.

Comment: Ха))) Спасибо. Я даже как-то не попробовал return. Завтыкал....

Comment: это хорошо — будет ответ на элементарный вопрос из разряда «часто задаваемых». прекрасно укладывается в парадигму сайта.

Answer (score 2):

Видимо вам нужно просто возвращать значение через `return`:

```golang
import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func Index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    parametr = 0
    if parametr != "1" {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Параметр=1")
        return
    }
    fmt.Fprintln(w, "текст после проверки") //Я хочу это не отображать,если parametr!="1"
} //Нужно,если параметр не 1
```